# Why do some airlines have different flight numbers for IATA and ICAO?

Tags: air-traffic-control, icao, flight-schedules, iata, call-sign

Most of the time when I see flights on either flightradar24 or flightaware it doesn't matter whether you use the 2-digit IATA code or the 3-digit ICAO code, the flight number is the same, i.e. a flight will be listed as UA1234/UAL1234.

But some airlines show different flight numbers for IATA and ICAO. Just picking a couple of random flights I can see on Flightradar24:

- SunExpress flight XQ231/SXS5J
- Pegasus Airlines flight PC398/PGT35R
- Turkish Airlines flight TK656/THY3YE

I've also seen this on RyanAir (FR/RYR) flights. Why do the IATA and ICAO identifiers have different flight numbers?